# Why can’t the second-derivative of a function (with respect to some variable) be written as follows?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let us suppose we have a function $f(r)$, where $r$ itself is a function, $r(x,y,z)$.

Why is it incorrect to write:

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2} \cdot \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x^2} $$
[The PDE equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFOlh.jpg)

Please forgive my lack of knowledge on this topic. I would really like to understand why this is the case.

Comment: Hi, I typed the math pretty for you. You can learn how to do it here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: For example let $r(x)=x^2$ and $f(r)=r$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Calvin Khor. I’ll definitely use it the next time I ask a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first derivative gives you a product via the chain rule:
$$
\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}(f\circ r) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r} f \cdot \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}r
$$
As a consequence we have to deal with the Leibniz rule in the next step. It is basically what defines a derivative besides linearity: $D_p(f\cdot r)= (D_{r(p)}f)\cdot r +f\cdot (D_pr).$ You cannot just drop one of the terms. 'Multiplication becomes addition by differentiation' is a rule of thumb. It is a deep truth hidden in the Leibniz rule, since in the end it corresponds to the functional formula of the exponential function, which is why differential equations can often be solved by using an ansatz with the exponential function.

Comment: It took me some time to understand it, but the insight is brilliant. Composite functions are converted to a multiplication of two functions, and that multiplication ultimately becomes addition. Thanks a lot for the answer!